# Split values in CSV that look like JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

So I have a CSV file with a column called content. However, the contents in column look like it is based on JSON, and, therefore, house more columns. I would like to split these contents into multiple columns or extract the final part of it after "value". See picture below to see an example of the file. Any ideas how to get this? I would prefer using Python. I don't have any experience with JSON. [image]

Comment: It would help greatly if you post a single line of the CSV file you *have* and the desired output you *want*, so it's clear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the first post with a new screenshot showing what i have and what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pandas you could do in a simpler way.
**EDIT** updated to handle the single quotes:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter="\n")["content"]
res = [json.loads(row.replace("'", '"')) for row in data]
result = pd.DataFrame(res)

result.head()
# Export result to CSV
result.to_csv("result.csv")
```

my csv:
[image]

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately i get the following error. json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: My bad, my example file was not the same as yours (I had double quotes). My answer is updated to adapt to single quotes.

Comment: Now it works, thanks!

Comment: if I wanted to export this to a CSV, what should I do?

Comment: that's the beauty of pandas! Simply: `result.to_csv("result.csv")`

Answer (score 1):

This script will create a new csv file with the 'value' added to the csv as an additional column

(make sure that the input_csv and output_csv are different filenames)

```
import csv
import json

input_csv = "data.csv"
output_csv = "data_updated.csv"

values = []
with open(input_csv) as f_in:
    dr = csv.DictReader(f_in)
    for row in dr:
        value = json.loads(row["content"].replace("'", '"'))["value"]
        values.append(value)


with open(input_csv) as f_in:
    with open(output_csv, "w+") as f_out:
        w = csv.writer(f_out, lineterminator="\n")
        r = csv.reader(f_in)

        all = []
        row = next(r)
        row.append("value")
        all.append(row)

        i = 0
        for row in r:
            row.append(values[i])
            all.append(row)
            i += 1

        w.writerows(all)
```